# Use IS NULL and IS NOT NULL instead of direct NULL comparisons in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube, sonarcloud

I have this sql query:

```sql
ALTER TABLE outfit
    ADD CONSTRAINT check_non_empty_string CHECK (image_uri <> '');
```

This works good but SonarCloud raised this as a bug. I am using PostgreSQL 13.2, is there a better way of writing this query or can I safely ignore this error in SonarCloud?

**Use IS NULL and IS NOT NULL instead of direct NULL comparisons.**

> In a Zen-like manner, "NULL" is never equal to anything, even itself. Therefore comparisons using equality operators will always return False, even when the value actually IS NULL.

> For that reason, comparison operators should never be used to make comparisons with NULL; IS NULL and IS NOT NULL should be used instead. This extends as well to empty string (""), which is equivalent to NULL for some database engines.

Answer (score 0):

The check constraint is good as it is, if you want to allow NULL values. Note that a check constraint passes if the result of the expression is NULL.

If you want to forbid NULL values as well, you should additionally do this:

```
ALTER TABLE outfit ALTER image_uri SET NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hi Laurenz - again :) This was the original column definition `image_uri text NOT NULL`,
The issue is that we had empty strings inserted and we wanted to make sure both values - empty string and null would not be allowed.

Comment: Then your definition is good as it is.

Comment: Since Postgres does not consider the empty string '' to be the same as NULL you need both `NOT NULL` and the chcck constraint..

Comment: Thank you, I will just ignore Sonar warning in that case.